# process with openmpi is killed despite nohup command

Tags: openmpi, nohup

I have used GAMESS for quantum computation in serial mode. I started to use it in parallel mode and it looks successful. But when I close my ssh terminal, the process is killed despite nohup command. In the log file, there is message "mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 2254 on node *** exited on signal 1 (Hangup)". How can I solve this problem? :(

Comment: Use tmux and run it in that. Then you can disconnect and reconnect to it any time without needing nohup.

Comment: Thank you!!! Using tmux, there is no problem. It was perfect help. Thank you, again. :)